# CoreData: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on private queue with Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error when I try to save context (second call to privateManagedObjectContext.hasChanges method).

Here is my method to save context:

```
func saveContext(#wait: Bool, completion: ((error: NSError?) -> ())?) {
    if mainManagedObjectContext.hasChanges || privateManagedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        if mainManagedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            mainManagedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait({ () -> Void in
                var error: NSError? = nil

                if !self.mainManagedObjectContext.save(&error) {
                    println("Error saving main managed object context \(error)")

                    if completion != nil {
                        completion!(error: error)
                    }

                    return
                }
            })
        }

        let saveBlock: () -> Void = {
            var error: NSError? = nil

            if self.privateManagedObjectContext.save(&error) {
                if completion != nil {
                    completion!(error: nil)
                }
            } else {
                println("Error saving private managed object context \(error)")

                if completion != nil {
                    completion!(error: error)
                }
            }
        }

        if self.privateManagedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            if (wait) {
                self.privateManagedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait(saveBlock)
            } else {
                self.privateManagedObjectContext.performBlock(saveBlock)
            }

            return
        }

        if completion != nil {
            completion!(error: nil)
        }
    } else {
        // No changes
        if completion != nil {
            completion!(error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I declared contexts like so:

```
    privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCoordinator

    mainManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    mainManagedObjectContext.parentContext = privateManagedObjectContext
```

What did I wrong here?

Comment: Remove performBlockAndWait and use performBlock. Alter your logic accordingly.http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/93355099502/performblock-vs-performblockandwait

Comment: @quellish Why is it so, that the private queue has to be called using performBlockAndWait, I saw your post but cannot find any reasoning for any of equivalent cases.

Comment: For none of the cases in the code that was posted would performBlockAndWait be the correct method to use. performBlockAndWait behaves very differently than performBlock, and is used for very different scenarios. It is not ideal to use for a save operation.

Comment: I didn't help, I am getting the same error all the time.